# Expected value of expression

Tags: algorithm, math

How can I find the expected value for the expression in form `P/Q`

> Given:
> N integers
> 2 Operators, 'Bitwise OR' & '+'

We can use any of the two operator with equal probability between each consecutive integers to form the expression.

Currently, the solution that I have in mind is to generate all possible expression using the operators and then using the value of each expression I can calculate expected value for it.

But as N grows, this approach fails. Is there any other alternative that will be efficient in terms of time complexity?

> Note: For this question: 'Bitwise OR' has higher priority than '+' operator.
>
> There can be at max 10^5 integers.

Example:

```
Input
1 2 3

Output
19/4
```

The different ways are:

```
1+2+3 = 6

1+2|3 = 4

1|2+3 = 6

1|2|3 = 3
```

All these ways have probability = `1/4`

So expected value will be `19/4`

Comment: Are you sure it's a programming question? Or to find the expectation by some logic?

Comment: Can you give an example? Can the integers be negative?

Comment: You can reduce the effort quite a bit using DP.

Comment: @A.S.H yes, its programming question.

Comment: @IVlad: I have added an example. No the numbers cannot be negative.

Comment: @Paul: Can you explain how?

Comment: Is this from a programming competition? What are the constraints on the count of numbers and their values?

Comment: @D.Khaneja [Razimans answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41751733/4668606) explains precisely what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The important observation is that every `+` splits its left and right parts into sections that can be processed independently.

Let the array of numbers be `a[1…N]`. Define `f(i)` to be the expectation value obtained from `a[i…N]`. What we want to find is `f(1)`.

Note that the first `+` sign in `[i…N]` will appear after the `i`th element with probability `1/2` and `i+1`th element with probability `1/4` and so on. Just find bitwise or of the elements till `+` and add the expectation value of what remains.

Thus we have the recurrence

`f(i) = sum_{j = i to N-1} (or(a[i…j]) + f(j+1))/(2^(j-i+1))
      + or(a[i…N])/(2^(N-i))`

This should be easy to implement efficiently without errors.

For the example array `[1,2,3]`:

- f(3) = or(a[3…3]) = 3
- f(2) = (or(a[2…2])+f(3))/2 + or(a[2…3])/2 = 5/2 + 3/2 = 4
- f(1) = (or(a[1…1])+f(2))/2 + (or(a[1…2])+f(3))/4 + or(a[1…3])/4 = 5/2 + 6/4 + 3/4 = 19/4

The answer is found to be 19/4, as expected.

Comment: I'm unable to get the correct answer using your approach. Can you please elaborate it using the example above?

Comment: Added. What are you getting different from this?

Comment: Since I need P & Q separately, so I ignored division by 2 in each term and calculated the numerator part only. Because denominator will always be `2^(N-1)` . Is there any modification required to calculate only P? I'm getting 18 in place of 19 in numerator.

Comment: You can try modifying the recurrence to find f(i)*2^(N-i) in that case. Try comparing with my step-by-step solution to see which of us is making an error.

Comment: Also the time complexity of above is `O(N^2)`. Is there any way that can be reduced to `O(NlogN)` by some precomputation?

Comment: You can sum up the `or(a[i…j])` term and the `f(j+1))/(2^(j-i+1)` term separately in a smart way to get N log N, try to come up with that :)

Comment: I have been trying to reduce the complexity for this part in other answer as well. If you can give me an approach or a reference, I can work on that.

Also, since I'm working with C++ , due to limit in value that can be stored, I cannot compute the terms with denominator having `2^x` for large x. So any other alternative to the recurrence?

Comment: Give a link to the source of the problem.

Comment: I don't have the link. My friend asked me this problem few days back.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since there are `2ⁿ⁻¹` expressions (two possible operators on each of the `n-1` places between numbers) and they are all equally probable, the expected value is the sum of all the expressions divided by `2ⁿ⁻¹`. So the problem boils down to calculating the sum of the expressions.

### An `O(n²)` algorithm

Let `x_1, x_2, ..., x_n` be the input numbers.

Let `S_k` be the sum of all expressions formed by inserting `|` or `+` between every pair of consecutive numbers in the list `x_1, x_2, ..., x_k`.

Let `N_k` be the number of all such expressions. `N_k = 2 ^ (k - 1)`.

Let's see how we can use `S_1, S_2, ..., S_(k-1)` to calculate `S_k`.

The idea is to divide all possible expressions by the position of the last `"+"` in them.

1. The sum of the expressions of the form `"... + x_k"` is

   - `S_(k-1) + x_k * N_(k-1)`
2. The sum of the expressions of the form `"... + x_(k-1) | x_k"` is

   - `S_(k-2) + (x_(k-1) | x_k) * N_(k-2)`
3. The sum of the expressions of the form `"... + x_(k-2) | x_(k-1) | x_k"` is

   - `S_(k-2) + (x_(k-2) | x_(k-1) | x_k) * N_(k-3)`
4. ...and so on until the single expression `x_1 | x_2 | ... | x_k`.

Here is a Python implementation of the algorithm.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3] # The input numbers.
totals = [0]        # The partial sums. For every k > 0 totals[k] is S_k.

for i in range(len(numbers)):  # Processing the numbers one by one.
    new_total = 0
    last_summand = 0           # last_summand is numbers[j] | ... | numbers[i]
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):  # j is the position of the last plus in the expression.
        # On every iteration new_total is increased by the sum of the 
        # expressions of the form "... + numbers[j] | ... | numbers[i]".
        last_summand |= numbers[j]
        new_total += totals[j] + last_summand * (2 ** (j - 1))
    last_summand |= numbers[0]
    new_total += last_summand  # Handling the expression with no pluses at all.
    totals.append(new_total)

# Now the last element in totals is the sum of all expressions.
print(str(totals[-1]) + '/' + str(2**(len(numbers) - 1)))
```

### Further optimization: `O(n*log(M))`

The problem has two properties that can be used to create a faster algorithm.

1. If `S_n` is the sum of the expressions formed by the numbers `x_1, x_2, ..., x_n`, then `2*S_n` is the sum of the expressions formed by the numbers `2*x_1, 2*x_2, ..., 2*x_n`.
2. If `x_1, x_2, ..., x_n` and `y_1, y_2, ..., y_n` are such that `x_k & y_m == 0` for any `k` and `m`, and `SX_n` is the sum of the expressions formed by `x_1, x_2, ..., x_n`, and `SY_n` is the sum of the expressions formed by `y_1, y_2, ..., y_n`, then `SX_n + SY_n` is the sum of the expressions formed by `x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2, ..., x_n+y_n`.

Which means, the problem can be reduced to finding the sum of the expressions for 1-bit numbers. Every bit position from `0` to `31` can be processed separately, and after the solutions are found we can simply add them.

Let `x_1, x_2, ..., x_n` be one-bit numbers (every `x_i` is either `0` or `1`).

Let `S_k` be the sum of the expressions formed by `x_1, x_2, ..., x_k`.

Let `N0_k` be the number of such expressions where the last summand equals 0.

Let `N1_k` be the number of such expressions where the last summand equals 1.

Here is the recurrent relation that allows to find `S_k`, `N0_k` and `N1_k` knowing only `x_k`, `S_(k-1)`, `N0_(k-1)` and `N1_(k-1)`:

1. `k = 1, x_1 = 0`:

   - `S_1 = 0`
   - `N0_1 = 1`
   - `N1_1 = 0`
2. `k = 1, x_1 = 1`:

   - `S_1 = 1`
   - `N0_1 = 0`
   - `N1_1 = 1`
3. `k > 1, x_k = 0`:

   - `S_k = S_(k-1) * 2`
   - `N0_k = N0_(k-1) * 2 + N0_(k-1)`
   - `N1_k = N1_(k-1)`
4. `k > 1, x_k = 1`:

   - `S_k = S_(k-1) * 2 + N0_(k-1) * 2 + N0_(k-1)`
   - `N0_k = 0`
   - `N1_k = N0_(k-1) * 2 + N0_(k-1) * 2`

Since `S_n` can be found in `O(n)` and it needs to be found for every bit position, the time complexity of the whole algorithm is `O(n*log(M))`, where `M` is the upper bound on the numbers.

An implementation:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
max_bits_in_number = 31

def get_bit(x, k):
    return (x >> k) & 1

total_sum = 0
for bit_index in range(max_bits_in_number):
    bit = get_bit(numbers[0], bit_index)
    expression_sum = bit
    expression_count = (1 - bit, bit)
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        bit = get_bit(numbers[i], bit_index)
        if bit == 0:
            expression_sum = expression_sum * 2
            expression_count = (expression_count[0] * 2 + expression_count[1], expression_count[1])
        else:
            expression_sum = expression_sum * 2 + expression_count[0] * 2 + expression_count[1]
            expression_count = (0, expression_count[0] * 2 + expression_count[1]*2)
    total_sum += expression_sum * 2**bit_index

print(str(total_sum) + '/' + str(2**(len(numbers) - 1)))
```

Comment: There can be upto `10^5` integers. So this `O(N^2)` solution  will not be time efficient. Is there any optimized approach?

Comment: How large can a single integer be?

Comment: Each integer will be in range `[0, 10^9]`

Comment: @Khaneja I added another algorithm that is linear with respect to N (and logarithmic with respect to the bound on the numbers).